# Usage of Relative adverbs in German. Which ones are correct to use?

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Could you please help me to overcome one confusion about the usage of relative adverbian.  Here is my examples; I wrote them with all alternative adverbs and asking you which ones are correct to use.

Thanks in advance.

1- Ich habe ein neues Buch gekauft, **das/was/welches** ich die zeigen möcht

2- Ich habe Liste mit Verben, **die/welche** ich immer erweitere.

3- Sie suchen für ihren Bereich Marketing einen Mitarbeiter, **der/wer** mit soliden Fachkentnissen die Qualität Ihrer Außendarstellung sichert.

4- Wer ist der netteste Mensch, **den/welchen** du bisher in Berlin getroffen hast?

5- Der Mann, **dem/welchem** ich Geld gelieben habe ist weggelaufen.

6-

Der Baum, **unter dem** wir ein Picknick gemacht haben, ist der älteste im Park.

Der Baum, **worunter** wir ein Picknick gemacht haben, ist der älteste im Park.

Der Baum, **darunter** wir ein Picknick gemacht haben, ist der älteste im Park.

7-

Er ist zu meiner Party gekommen, **worüber/über die/darüber** ich mich sehr gefreut habe.

Comment: Sorry, this looks a bit too much like homework you are trying to off-load. Can you please improve your answer by adding your own reasoning?

Comment: Sorry it is nothing about homework. If you think so you should not help.  And if you read carefully reason is already written by me..  confusion I am facing to use language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Ich habe ein neues Buch gekauft, das/welches ich **Dir** zeigen möcht**e**

I guess the "die" should be "Dir" (I want to show it to you)
Das or welches is both correct, was would be wrong

> 2- Ich habe Liste mit Verben, die/welche ich immer erweitere.

both is correct

> 3- Sie suchen für ihren Bereich Marketing einen Mitarbeiter, der mit soliden Fachken**n**tnissen die Qualität Ihrer Außendarstellung sichert.

wer is wrong

> 4- Wer ist der netteste Mensch, den du bisher in Berlin getroffen hast?

welchen would be possible but uncommon

> 5- Der Mann, dem ich Geld gelie**h**en habe ist weggelaufen.

same as 4

> 6- Der Baum, unter dem wir ein Picknick gemacht haben, ist der älteste im Park.

The other two are wrong

> 7-Er ist zu meiner Party gekommen, worüber ich mich sehr gefreut habe.

this means you were happy about that person coming to your party (probably the one you wanted to express

> Er ist zu meiner Party gekommen, über die ich mich sehr gefreut habe.

that would mean that you were happy about the party (maybe someone else organized that party for you?)

the third variant (darüber) is wrong

Comment: r/e= typo... could we just say: die/welche etc are equal?

Comment: Thanks for complete answer. Lastly I want to ask  2 more points

1- Then why can we use "was" in the following example while not above.

• Das ist ein Lebensmittel, was/das/welches   ich essen kann

2-  related to 6. question above, why can we not use "worunter". Because we can use "worüber" and "über die" both in 7. question

Answer (score 1):

das Buch, **was** is wrong. der,die,das and welcher, welche, welches are interchangeabel.

Volkers answer is correct.